# Using output of Matlab protected file as input in Matlab

Tags: matlab, optimization, protected

I am aware that .p files are Matlab protected files. So, I am not trying to access them. However, I was wondering if I could use their output onto the Matlab shell as input to a Matlab program.

What I mean is the following: I have to simulate a dynamic system in Matlab using a controller. Afterwards, I need to assess its performance. This is done by the .p file. Now, the controller behaviour is defined by six distinct variables. I pretty much know their range. So, what I did was create an optimization to find the optimal coefficients. However, when I run the .p file I see that the coefficients I obtained as optimal are in fact not optimal, i.e. my cost function is biased in some way.

So, what I would like to do is to use the output of the .p file (there are always six strings with only two numerical values - so they would be easy to extract if it were a text file) to run a new optimization so that I can understand what I did wrong in my original cost function.

The alternative is finding the parameters starting from my values by trial and error, but considering there are six variables I would prefer a more mathematically pure approach.

Basically, the question is how I can read the output onto the command prompt of a Matlab .p function, and use it as input in a Matlab function.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yes you can take the outputs of an .p file and do whatever you want with them. What is the question again?

Comment: If I see the output of the .p file, then how can I read it from a Matlab script. What I am trying to do is run the .p file from within the cost function, read the output and set the numerical values as the cost.

Comment: You should be able to call things in the .p file as though it were defined normally

Comment: The difference betweeen a .p and a .m file should only be that you can not see one

Comment: Ok, thanks. So, if I run it from the command prompt, for instance if it were example.p, I would run: `example` . Then, how can I import the text on the Matlab prompt into a program?